# angular controller reuse causing scope issue

Tags: angularjs

I'm using the same controller and view twice on a page, and loading different data into the scope. It seemed to be working fine until I clicked on a button and the ng-click handler had the scope from the other controller instance. Is there a way to fix/avoid this?

Comment: Make [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) or plunker

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like converting your scope+view pair into a directive will solve your issue, but hard to say without any source code in the question